# htcaccess redirect sub directory to single page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Id like to make sure I have this right before I test this on the live site.  Before I started working for my current employer they did a website update but did not keep the same URL naming structure.  So we are still getting 404 crawl errors on Google even with our Sitemap updated.  It will list the old URL and then say then list old links as where they are Linked From.  I'm not sure what I need to correct this.

The old structure was domain.com/product/12345/product_name.

The new structure is domain.com/category-name/12-product-name.  There's really no way to match the old product urls to the new.  Some of the names have changed.

So I want to redirect all the pages from the /product/ directory to a single page, either the home page or an all inventory page.

I already have the rewrite rule on

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect all the pages in the product directory should I add:

```
 RedirectMatch 301  ^/product/(.*) http://domain.com/
```

I also saw it with a RewriteRule and RedirectPermanent.  Not sure which is the best practice for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all rules using `mod_rewrite` module:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^product/.* / [L,NC,R=301]
```